# Unexpected behaviour when extending the mysql Dockerfile

Tags: mysql, docker

I created the following Dockerfile:

```
FROM mysql:5.7

ADD assets/geograph.cnf /etc/mysql/conf.d

ENV MYSQL_DATABASE=geograph \
    MYSQL_RANDOM_ROOT_PASSWORD=yes

ADD http://data.geograph.org.uk/dumps/gridimage_base_sample.mysql.gz /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/gridimage_base_sample.sql.gz
```

I then created an image from this Dockerfile:

```
docker build --tag geograph:latest .
```

I then created a container from this image:

```
docker run --name geograph -e MYSQL_USER=geograph -e MYSQL_PASSWORD=geograph --detach geograph:latest
```

However, I've noticed some unexpected behaviour:

1. The container starts and then stops. (I've compared `docker ps` and `docker ps --all`.)
2. The `geograph` database doesn't contain the data from `gridimage_base_sample.sql.gz`, which was created by `mysqldump`. (I've verified the database dump.)

I expected the container to behave like [the base MySQL image](https://hub.docker.com/_/mysql/) (`mysql:5.7`), with some additional configuration and some data. What am I doing wrong?

**Some context:** I'd like to use the database for analysis, ensuring that the results of my analysis are repeatable. I'm not going to be creating/deleting records and host/guest will probably be on the same machine. I've experimented with using another image/container to curl the database dump into a [volume](https://docs.docker.com/storage/volumes/) and then mounting this volume when creating the `geograph` container. This solves #2 but not #1. (It also seems a bit unnecessary to have two images/containers but that's not terribly important: if two are required, then two are required!)

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: Check container logs - I guess there will some error.

Comment: Thanks for the nudge @JanGaraj. The container logs were very revealing!

Answer (score 0):

Whilst the above image could `ADD` the database dump, the MySQL image couldn't unzip it because of a permissions error. (The user didn't have permission to write to `/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d`.) Seemingly this was enough to cause the container to stop (#1) and explains why the `geograph` database didn't contain the data from `gridimage_base_sample.sql.gz` (#2).